# Can't request install of my liveapp: Server Error

Tags: quip, liveapps

When I try ti request an install of my app, clicking the "Request Install" button, it shows a server error.

Is this error transient? Is there a workaround for it?

[image]

Comment: Are you an admin of your site with live apps access?

Comment: I'm not an admin